# Adding multiple resources with the same name to Xcode for iPhone

Tags: iphone, resources, ios

Is it possible to use double names for images into the resource group?

Thanks :)

Comment: What are "double names"?

Comment: For example "/cars/background.png", "/bikes/background.png". But when i use it in my code or in Interface Builder i only get one "background.png"..

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You can have multiple resources with the same name as long as (1) they are not in the same directory, and (2) You've added the resources to your Xcode project by reference.

(1) because no directory can contain two files with the same name

(2) because Xcode respects directory structures for directories added by reference (if you add it directly to the project, Xcode tosses everything into the root level of the application bundle)

Comment: Oke thanks, but at Interface Builder i only see 1 image with the same name, but i add 2 images with the same name in different groups.

And also into some Objective-C code i use "test.png" and not "cars/test.png" with the group name, sorry i'm a bit confused.

Comment: To elaborate: Add "cars" as a "folder reference" (it gives you the option when you drag it into Xcode) and load the image using imageNamed:"cars/background.png". Note that this potentially misses an important step: it does *not* run `pngcrush -iphone` on the images (it simply copies the directory contents), so they potentially load slower on device.

Comment: Avoid using this approach with your Resources folder directly or your builds will fail. Other reference folders within Resources seem to be fine.

Comment: Can you elaborate on how to add by reference? I'm adding the files with the reference checkbox marked but I'm still getting errors when building. Even using legacy build.

Comment: This is no longer allowed with Swift 5.8 https://github.com/apple/swift-evolution/blob/main/proposals/0274-magic-file.md