# Asset Catalog: Access images with same name in different folders

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, bundle, assets

There is an `images.xcassets` in my project, it contains an `icons` folder and two subfolders (`firstFolder`, `secondFolder`) with images. Both of my subfolders have the same number of icons and the *same icons names* (for different themes of my app).

So what I'm looking for:
I need to get the needed icon(for current theme) from my bundle.

I've tried to do something like this:

```
NSBundle* bundle = [NSBundle bundleForClass:[self class]];
NSString *imageName = [bundle.bundlePath stringByAppendingPathComponent:@"icons/firstFolder/neededIcon"];
```

It does not work.

Comment: Please don't overuse bold formatting. It's very hard on the eyes.

Comment: Ok, I got it. Thanks.

Answer (score 80, accepted):

Click on each folder in the assets catalog and select `Provides Namespace` in the Utilities View:

[image]

You will see that the folder then becomes blue and you can see the path to the image above the images.

You can then access the image like this:

```
imageView.image = UIImage(named: "folder1/Image")
```

or in Objective-C:

```
imageView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"folder1/Image"];
```

Comment: Actually for Objective-C it's should be smth like this: imageView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"icons/firstFolder/neededIcon"];

Comment: The path depends on the folder structure you use in your assets catalog. I used the path that fits to the screenshot above. I'll add a Objective-C snippet to my answer

Comment: Thanks. Great answer!

Comment: Hey @joern do u have any idea how to calculate number of images present in that folder1 ?

Comment: Hey @ShrikantKankatti. I don't know if that's possible, but if you find a way, please let us know.