# How to load specific folder from XCAsset?

Tags: ios, uicolor, xcasset

In my app I have a color.xcasset with following structure:
color.xcasset

```
 ->Red
   ->primarycolor
   ->secondarycolor
   ->backgroundcolor
   ->headercolor
 ->Blue
   ->primarycolor
   ->secondarycolor
   ->backgroundcolor
   ->headercolor
 ->Yellow
   ->primarycolor
   ->secondarycolor
   ->backgroundcolor
   ->headercolor
```

Now I want to load only one folder at a time and that i will specify/select somewhere in app or in code.
For example: When I choose to apply red theme to my app, it should load red folder. Same for blue and yellow themes.
How I can do this?

Comment: Does it need to be swappable at run time? or will you compile the app with the theme being used

Comment: maybe [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33285214/1219956) will solve your problem? keep the namespace as a variable somewhere and access your images like "\(theme)/imageName"

Comment: @Fonix both, at runtime and build time.